# Sharepoint set the value of created by field to equal modified by field using java script

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, people-picker

I am working on sharepoint workflow project through visual studio.I wanted to know if it is possible to set the value of created by field to equal modified by field using java script.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Created by" and "modified by" are standard SharePoint fields. They can not be altered. It is not supported by Microsoft. They represent the user who created the record and the user who modified the record for the last time.